# Input text child component does not show any text while typing passing onChange function from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have controller component "ManageAuthorPage" which passes props "setAuthorState" to "AuthorForm" (this prop function is responsible to update input state so that it will render child component).

"AuthorForm" is responsible to to show form which has additional input component "Input" where "setAuthorState" prop are again passed as props.

***Now typing in input component does not show any text in input field.***

Its confirmed that "setAuthorState" is triggred but checking state value showed that it is only updating a single key pressed and overrides with another one on next key stroke. But this does not show any text in textfield.

here are my content of three files:

1) ManageAuthorPage.js

```
"use strict";

var React = require('react');
var AuthorForm = require('./authorForm');

var ManageAuthorPage = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return{
            author: {id: '', firstName: '', lastName: ''}
        };
    },

    setAuthorState: function(event){
        var field = event.target.name; 
        var value = event.target.value; 
        this.state.author[field] = value;
        return this.setState({author: this.state.author});


    },

    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className="">
                <AuthorForm onChange={this.setAuthorState} author= {this.state.author} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = ManageAuthorPage;
```

2) AuthorForm.js

```
var React = require('react');

var Input = require('../common/textinput');


var AuthorForm = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <form>
                <h1>Manage author</h1>
                <Input 
                    name="first Name"
                    label = "First Name"
                    onChange= {this.props.onChange}
                     value={this.props.author.firstName}
                />

                <Input 
                    name="last Name"
                    label = "Last Name"
                    onChange= {this.props.onChange}
                     value={this.props.author.lastName}
                />

                 <br />
                 <input type="submit" value="Save" className="btn btn-default" />
            </form>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = AuthorForm;
```

3) textInput.js

```
"use strict"

var React = require('react');

var Input = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired, 
        label: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired, 
        onChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired, 
        placeholder: React.PropTypes.string, 
        value: React.PropTypes.string, 
        error: React.PropTypes.string
    },
    render: function(){
        var wrapperClass = 'form-group';
        if(this.props.error && this.props.error.length > 0){
            wrapperClass += " " + 'has-error';
        }
        return(

            <div className={wrapperClass}>
                <label htmlFor={this.props.name}>{this.props.label}</label>
                <div className="field">
                    <input type="text"
                        name={this.props.name}
                        className="form-control"

                        ref={this.props.name}
                        value={this.props.value} 
                        onChange={this.props.onChange} />
                     <div className="input">{this.props.error}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = Input;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got two errors.

1º You are mutating the state directly on `setAuthorState()`

```
setAuthorState: function(event){
    var field = event.target.name; 
    var value = event.target.value; 
    this.state.author[field] = value;
    return this.setState({author: this.state.author});
}
```

should be

```
setAuthorState: function(event){
    var field = event.target.name; 
    var value = event.target.value; 
    var author = Object.assign({},this.state.author); // Clone state.author
    author[field] = value;
    return this.setState({author: author});
}
```

2º The `<input>` **name** should match the `state.author` property

```
<Input 
      name="first Name"
      label = "First Name"
      onChange= {this.props.onChange}
      value={this.props.author.firstName}
/>
<Input 
      name="last Name"
      label = "Last Name"
      onChange= {this.props.onChange}
      value={this.props.author.lastName}
/>
```

should be

```
<Input 
      name="firstName"
      label = "First Name"
      onChange= {this.props.onChange}
      value={this.props.author.firstName}
/>
<Input 
      name="lastName"
      label = "Last Name"
      onChange= {this.props.onChange}
      value={this.props.author.lastName}
/>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49670/)